# Background se distorsiona en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

cuando voy a colocar el background en la App de Android Studio esconde todos los widgets y ademas se ve distorsionada, ya la he trabajado con draw9patch y ademas intento crear el apk y me da este error

> Android resource compilation failed error: too many padding sections on bottom border.

Mi codigo XML es este

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="252dp"
    android:layout_height="98dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/w_text"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/in_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese error siempre se me presenta cuando tengo un un mal formato en los drawables que uso en el background, te recomiendo que cambies draw9patch por [Drawable Importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer)

Answer (score -1):

Imagino que todo eso esta dentro de un relativeLayout. Trata de crear un imagenView y que ese sea el background

```xml
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/background"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="252dp"
    android:layout_height="98dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/w_text"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/in_button" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```